# WooCommerce image issue makeing me panic

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Please help me with the product image issue along with the gap between two rows as shown in screen shot here http://prntscr.com/e0kge5. I tried using custom css and I don't know if the custom css plugin is not working or the code but there is no difference even after I enter css.

Here is an  [image of my problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21CBL.png)

Comment: Please give a more explicit description of the problem you would like help with, just posting an image and asking for help doesn't tell us what you need. Include what you want to happen, what is happening, and what you've already tried.

Comment: please share your live link so i can check my side @preeth